# Incorrect export method with React modules

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript

Why do I get

> React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number.
>
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Main`.

when trying to import my module from file? I have the following structure:

- app.cjsx

  - components/
  - index.coffee
  - App/

    - App.cjsx
    - index.coffee

app.cjsx:

```
React = require('react')
ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
injectTapEventPlugin = require('react-tap-event-plugin')
{getMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider} = require('material-ui/styles')
App = require('./components/App')
injectTapEventPlugin()

Main = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
      <App />
    </MuiThemeProvider>

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

components/index.coffee:

```
exports.App = require('./App')
```

components/App/index.coffee:

```
require('coffee-react/register')
module.exports = require('./App.cjsx')
```

components/App/App.cjsx:

```
React = require('react')
AppBar = require('material-ui/AppBar')
{Card, CardHeader, CardText} = require('material-ui/Card')

exports.default = React.createClass
  render: ->
    <AppBar title='Hello, world!' />
```

I'm using `coffee-react v5.0.0` and `coffee-react-transform v4.0.0`

Comment: Changing `exports.default` on `components/App/App.cjsx` to `module.exports` makes coffee-react create a class named `exports`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after hours of killing my brain trying to think why my exports weren't working, I figured out that the error wasn't in my exports, but in the way I imported Material UI AppBar:

```
AppBar = require('material-ui/AppBar')
```

So I changed it to

```
{AppBar} = require('material-ui')
```